# GraphQL simple nested query returning null field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm trying to learn GraphQL (& node.js & MongoDB etc.). I cant get this simple nested query to return results :

```
query getLocationByPerson {
   People {
      firstName
        lastName
        service {
        location
      }
   }
}
```

The result I get is :

```
{
  "data": {
    "People": [
      {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "DOE",
        "service": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Service.location.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 7
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "People",
        0,
        "service",
        "location"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All the code is available here : https://github.com/fabricezerrouki/graphql-playground
Can anyone have a look and help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you're setting the service attribute when you create and update a person. For nested types, you want to pass an object containing the subtypes. Right now you're passing it just a string, so when you try to set Service equal to args.serviceId in your createPerson resolver, it doesn't exist, and therefore sets the value of that field to null in MongoDB. Re-factor like so:

**In index.js**

```
type Mutation {
  createPerson(Xid: String!, firstName: String */ ... */ service: { id: ID!, name: String!, location: String! }): People!
}
```

**In /resolvers/Mutation.js**

```
const Mutations = {

  createPerson: async (parent, args) => {
    const newPerson = new People({
      Xid: args.Xid,
      firstName: args.firstName
      /* and so on... */
      Service: args.service.id
    });
  }

}
```

Also, you may run into problems in the future given the way your saving the Service object to MongoDB as a Capital "S" Service, whereas your variable in the queries is lowercase "s" service. You'll have to remember any time you search the database to now directly destructure the the args.service into your Model.find({service}) method. Kind of a niche problem, but I've ran into that exact problem myself, so figured I would mention it.

### **Edited in response to OP comment**

Yes it is possible to do an SQL join-link operation to return the Service object with the Person query, but you'll need to to that in the query resolver and just store the Service id during the mutation. In that case I guess the reason it's null is your calling `args.serviceId` but the createPerson() parameter is simply "service" so try changing Mutation.js to `Service: args.service`.

As for the actual join operation, that's a bit more complicated. I would recommend first returning the serviceId string to make sure that works correctly. Then you'll need to delve into the MongoDB [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html). More specifically, the [$lookup pipeline operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) performs a function similar to an SQL join. I end up banging my head against the wall every time I have to deal with aggregation pipelines. It's a pretty advanced subject with a confusing syntax IMO. But there are plenty of tutorials and examples out there for doing exactly what your wanting.

Comment: thanks. Actually I have two mongoDB collections : "peoples" and "services". In each peoples' document I have a 'service' objectId which matches with the services' documents '_id'. I would use it somehow like a SQL join. Is it possible? Do you need a screenshot of the mongodb collections?

Comment: Check out my edit and let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: thanks again. Just to be clear : the createPerson mutation is working just fine, the issue is only with the nested query I've posted earlier. When I update as you adviced, the 'service' field is now null.
I just tried to return the service's "id" instead of the location field, still "null" result.

Comment: I suppose I'm a bit confused, I saw that the input is "service" in index.js line 37, but it's being accessed as "serviceId" in Mutation.js line 11. If it aint broke, I suppose. Try some troubleshooting and see what results you get: remove the bang(!) from the Service type definition so they are no longer required. That will get rid of the error so you can see what is actually sent back. Also, console.log the result of Service.findByID(service) in Query.js line 5 to make sure there's not a async function returning a promise instead of fully resolving.

Comment: I updated the repository with the last modifications I made thanks to you, but still not working :(